# Push trailing widget to bottom of Flutter Navigation Rail

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can one push the trailing widget within a Flutter Navigation Rail to the bottom of the rail? I thought it would be as simple as wrapping the trailing widget with an Expanded widget, but I get the usual flutter **needs paint** error message.

I can get it working if I add a `Column` with a first child of `SizedBox` with a fixed height, and then the widget I want to display, but I need the **spacer** to fill the available space, not a fixed height. Here's the `SizedBox` example which does indeed fill 200px of space, but how do I get it to fill the available space?

```dart
// other navrail properties....

     trailing: Column(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 200,
          ),
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.settings), onPressed: () {})
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't! One way would be to copy the NavigationRail code and tweak the trailing part so that it would be Expanded.

Comment: wow, that's a pain. I might be looking at submitting my first feature request then!

Comment: I tried until I realized its not possible. Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is not hard, use Expanded with Align widgets:

```js
NavigationRail(
  selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
  destinations: _destinations,
  trailing: Expanded(
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
        child: IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.help), onPressed: (){}),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: As side effect, "destinations" end pushed up to top...

Comment: This works well. Any idea on how to make it work when you have a `Column` within the `trailing` section? (e.g. when you need some text alongside the button)?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution (or workaround):

Put the `NavigationRail` and an `Positioned` widget in a `Stack`:

```
  Scaffold(
    body: Row(
      children: [
        Stack(
          children: [
            NavigationRail(
              selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
              extended: Styling.isLargeScreen(context),
              destinations: _destinations
                  .map((d) => d.toNavigationDestination)
                  .toList(),
              onDestinationSelected: (index) => _onItemTapped(index),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.amber,
                height: 100,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: _buildPage(_destinations.elementAt(_selectedIndex).key),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Hopefully it gets fixed soon!

Answer (score 0):

I tried Ricardo's answer, a widget I put aligned in the center of `NavigationRail`.

Inside the `NavigationRail`, it uses `Column`, which is where destinations and trailing are placed. As you know, the default value of the `crossAxisAlignment` of `Column` is `crossAxisAlignment.center`.

But I want my widget to be aligned from the left side, Below worked fine.

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    // left area
    Column(
      // You can choose start, center, left.
      // baseline, strech results runtime error!
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        // NavigationRail
        Expanded(
          child: NavigationRail(
            selectedIndex: _selected,
            destinations: _destinations,
          ),
        ),
        // bottom
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Text('bottom-left text'),
        )
      ],
    ),
    // right area
    Expanded(
      child: _content,
    ),
  ],
)
```